# Custom Loadstring function

Tags: lua

Is it possible to recreate [loadstring](http://www.gammon.com.au/scripts/doc.php?lua=loadstring)? using [this](http://pastebin.com/N9NVk9v1) lua tree.

Comment: There is probably a good reason that it is hidden

Comment: It is possible to write an interpreter of Lua inside Lua  :)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff A crazy idea, so someone already has done it. [LiL - completely pointless Lua interpreter written in Lua](http://www.computercraft.info/forums2/index.php?/topic/1868-lil-completely-pointless-lua-interpreter-written-in-lua/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer - **no**.

You're probably working inside a sandbox of some sort. `loadstring` is the main function for compiling strings into Lua code and there is no alternative way to do it from within Lua. As in most sandboxes, the function most likely exists somewhere highier than your sandbox, but you won't get access to it from your script level, which has custom environment.

Comment: Actually `load` is, `loadstring` is a deprecated compatibility function (No behavior difference to `load` by call with proper argumant types).

Comment: @Deduplicator Depending on Lua version you're using (on the deprecated bit). Juding by the globals layout he provided, it's Lua 5.1. I didn't want to introduce unnecessary confusion into my answer.